# Pip is hanging when I try install anything, for hours. How can I fix this?

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

I have downloaded and installed the latest version of Anaconda v5.1. I have previously uninstalled / deleted all previous versions of python / Anaconda / pip the cache etc that I could find on the computer, Windows 10 and I am still getting this problem. I wasn't getting it before.

Typically what happens is the output you would normally see when installing a module but pip then hangs after the "Successfully installed XXX" message. I have to cancel the process with "Ctrl + C". If I try to import the module I just installed I get the message "No module named: XXX"

What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Run `pip install -vvv somepkg`, copy the complete output from the terminal and add it to the question.

Comment: I adding the output, from pip install -vvv Django. I had to cut out some of the "Found link" lines in order for it to fit character limit. Hopefully this isn't and issue @hoefling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I'm not sure what the issue really was, but I was able to resolve it. It seems to have been comodo antivirus. As I came accross other persons with a similar problem and they had comodo installed.

I removed comodo and the issue seems to have been resolved. It may have had something to do with the following file:
C:\Users\\AppData\Local\pip\cache\selfcheck.json

It seems like pip is trying to lock the file and is stuck in an infinite loop trying to achieve a lock.

I have also found that disabling the auto-containment on comodo also allows pip to function.